# conversion to doubleValue doesn't work .. but to integerValue does

Tags: objective-c

Hello all I'm trying to convert a string to a double and it doesn't work.
However if I convert it to an integer it does work

this is my code snippet

```
int myDuration = [myDurationString integerValue];
int conversionMinute = myDuration / 60;

            if( myDuration < 60 )
            {
                [appDelegate.rep1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",myDuration]];
                NSLog(@"show numbers %d", myDuration);
            }
            else
            {
                [appDelegate.rep1 addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",conversionMinute]];
                NSLog(@"show numbers %d", conversionMinute);
            }
```

Now if I try to do

```
double myDuration = [myDurationString doubleValue];
double conversionMinute = myDuration / 60;
```

then it doesn't work. It gives me an output of 0.

So the integerconversion works but somehow the double doesn't does anybody have an idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply a matching format specifier. Replace every occurence of `%d` with `%f`.

`%d` simply fetches the next 32-bit word from the stack and treats it as a signed integer. Because of the internal representation of the floating point number, this word is zero in quite a few cases, which is why you get 0.

Here is an example that works fine for me (also with other contents of `myDurationString`):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    NSString * myDurationString = @"19";
    double myDuration = [myDurationString doubleValue];
    double conversionMinute = myDuration / 60;  
    if( myDuration < 60 )
    {
        NSLog(@"show numbers %f", myDuration);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"show numbers %f", conversionMinute);
    }
    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer unfortunately I already tried to change the format specifier to %f and it didn't work. I indeed got zero , and after the change I got zero again.

Comment: you are correct I had a typo further down in my code ( not the snippet _